# Convert species regional occurence to presense/absence matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a dataframe where the first column is species name and the second column is where the species lives, coded by area. I want to convert this dataframe to a presence/absence matrix, where the rows are species names, the columns are the areas, and each record (following the header) is a series of 0s (denoting absence in a given region) and 1s (denoting presence in a given region).

Example input:

```
    species     regions
    species1    area1
    species2    area2,area3
    species3    area2,area3
```

Desired output:

```
   species  area1   area2   area3
   species1     1       0       0 
   species2     0       1       1
   species3     0       1       1
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this conversion in R?

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr`/`tidyr` approach would be to first separate `species` into different rows, `group_by` `species` and create a row identifier for each group and then `spread` it to wide format and since we want only presence absence information (1/0) we can change any number greater than 1 to 1.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(regions, sep = ",") %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  mutate(row= row_number()) %>%
  spread(regions, row, fill = 0) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("area")), ~replace(., . > 1, 1))

#  species  area1 area2 area3
#  <fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 species1     1     0     0
#2 species2     0     1     1
#3 species3     0     1     1
```

Comment: In my example, I used area1, area2, area3. What if there is no pattern to the area name? e.g. NAN, CAN, CDH

Comment: @user11501147 only issue might arise in the last step of `mutate_at`, in that case you can use column numbers then like `mutate_at(2:4, ~replace(., . > 1, 1))`

Answer (score 0):

We can do this easily with `base R` by splitting the 'regions' column by `,`, set the names of the `list` elements with 'species', convert the `list` to a two column data.frame with `stack` and get the frequency with `table`

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df1$regions, ","), df1$species)))
#     ind
#values  species1 species2 species3
#  area1        1        0        0
#  area2        0        1        1
#  area3        0        1        1
```

---

Or more compactly with `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1[1], mtabulate(strsplit(df1$regions, ",")))
#    species area1 area2 area3
#1 species1     1     0     0
#2 species2     0     1     1
#3 species3     0     1     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(species = c("species1", "species2", "species3"
), regions = c("area1", "area2,area3", "area2,area3")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```